# Gcov 6.0 with Ceedling 0.31.1 generates empty html report

Tags: unit-testing, gcov, gcovr, ceedling

I am trying to generate a html report using ceedling and gcov. But I keep getting a empty html report.
I have added report_include like this link mentions at the bottom of the page - https://github.com/ThrowTheSwitch/Ceedling/tree/master/plugins/gcov

```
:gcov:
  :reports:
  - HtmlDetailed
:gcovr:
  :html_medium_threshold: 75
  :html_high_threshold: 90
  :report_include: "^..Code/Src/*"
```

I have enabled gcov in the yml file. Ceedling and gcovr are installed.

Anything I try I always get a empty html report.

I did have it working a month ago with the report_include not using the ^ and including the whole Code folder.

```
:report_include: "..Code/*"
```

But now it does not want to work.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution to this finally...
Before I was running these commands:

```
ceedling test:all
ceedling utils:gcov
```

This does NOT give a html report instead to get this to work I had to run:

```
ceedling gcov:all utils:gcov
```

I am not 100% on this but I'm guessing it something to do with the plugins and any files they create, as before the gcov artifacts would not have anything in except the html reports, but after they have results and out files. So I assume it has something to do with that.

Run `ceedling gcov:all utils:gcov` to run the tests and get a html report. It does NOT seem possible to just generate the html report.

Answer (score 1):

I always use this:

```
ceedling clobber test:all gcov:all utils:gcov
```